# is there a way to make material ui drawer fixed height (and anchored the bottom)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, drawer

Trying to have a material-ui Drawer anchored to the bottom of the viewport, but of a fixed height - will have scrollbars for extra content.  Is this possible with a Drawer ?

```
<Drawer
  className={classes.drawer}
  variant="permanent"
  anchor="bottom"
  open={drawerOpen}
  classes={{
    paper: classes.drawerPaper,
  }}
>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set the height of the `Paper` element within your `drawerPaper` class.

For instance:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  drawerPaper: {
    width: 240,
    height: 300
  }
}));
```

And then use the `drawerPaper` class as shown in your question (`classes={{paper: classes.drawerPaper}}`).

[image: Edit Bottom drawer fixed height]

Comment: that was much easier than I thought  - thank you for the response!